# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TABLE NAME is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, playframework

I have two models, Item and ShopSection. They have a many-to-many relationship.

```
@Entity(name = "item")
public class Item extends Model
{
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public Set<ShopSection> sections;
}

@Entity(name = "shop_section")
public class ShopSection extends Model
{
    public List<Item> findActiveItems(int page, int length)
    {
        return Item.find("select distinct i from Item i join i.sections as s where s.id = ?", id).fetch(page, length);
    }
}
```

`findActiveItems` is meant to find items in a section, but I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Item is not mapped [select distinct i from Item i join i.sections as s where s.id = ?]
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:322)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3441)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3325)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:733)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:584)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
        at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:244)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:272)
        ... 8 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the `@Table` annotations like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item extends Model
{
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public Set<ShopSection> sections;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "shop_section")
public class ShopSection extends Model
{
    public List<Item> findActiveItems(int page, int length)
    {
        return Item.find("select distinct i from Item i join i.sections as s where s.id = ?", id).fetch(page, length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to select from "item" and not from "Item". Entity name is case sensitive.

Comment: this was my problem. thank you for this. can seem kinda obvious but you're not always working on code / tables that you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare Object in hibernate.cgf.xml